# Element on hover doesn't update

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to update an ul li when i hover on some tabs from a different ul. 
Every thing works okay for the first 2 tabs  but when i try to move to the 3rd tab first li it doesn't get updated even if i'm right on it(the color changes)

https://jsbin.com/zaqutayuku/edit?html,output

https://jsfiddle.net/fh9czspu/

```
$(".tabs").hover(function(){



  $('.nav > .tabs > .subnav').each(function(key,val){

        $(this).removeClass('show');

  });


  $(this).children('.subnav').addClass('show');

  $("#at > #one").text( $(this).children('p').text() );
  $("#at > #two").text("");

});


$(".subtab").hover(function(){

    $("#at > #two").text( $(this).text() );

});
```

Comment: Any errors in the developer's console? The problem is about showing new content or color change? As far as I saw your code, it worked "fine"

Comment: No, no error in dev console.The problem is updating the ul below when i'm on Test 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:
Firstly the jquery `hover()` function reacts to mouse enter and mouse leave events. So your events are doubled every time the user hovers a tab or a subtab. Furthermore the `tab` hover event is also executed, when a child `subtab` is hovered, because the child is part of the parent container.

I've edited your code and used jQuery's `mouseover()` function. The tab event is now on the `p` element with the tabs title. Also the cases when hovering a subtab at first is now contained in the JS part.

```
var menu;
var submenu;

$(".tabs p").mouseover(function(){
  $('.nav > .tabs > .subnav').each(function(key,val){
    $(this).removeClass('show');    
  });
  var parentTabs = $(this).parent('.tabs');

  parentTabs.children('.subnav').addClass('show');
    $("#at > #one").text($(this).text());
    $("#at > #two").text('');

});

$(".subtab").mouseover(function() {
    $("#at > #one").text($(this).closest('.tabs').children('p').text());
    $("#at > #two").text($(this).text());
});
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8L92a9ua/.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mouseenter` event and [delegated events](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(".tabs").mouseenter(function(){
  $('.nav > .tabs > .subnav').each(function(key,val){
        $(this).removeClass('show');
  });

  $(this).children('.subnav').addClass('show');

  $("#at > #one").text( $(this).children('p').text() );
  $("#at > #two").text("");
});

$(".nav").on('mouseenter', '.subtab', function(){
    $("#at > #two").text( $(this).text() );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fh9czspu/2/